# MySQL 5.7 recursive query on hierarchy data with unknown levels

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql5

I am developing a hierarchy data structure where I want to perform a recursion to get the desired output

```
 id       role_id      reporting_to
 ------+-------------+-----------------
1          100             101
1          101             102
1          102             103
1          103             104
```

I would like to get the following output if I gave `103` as input role

```
  id    role_id      reporting_to
-----------+-------------+-----------------
    1          100             101
    1          101             102
    1          102             103
```

The output should be from the input to till the last child. Tried following example, but it is not returning proper output

```
select id,role_id,reporting_to
from (select * from role_mapping order by reporting_to,id) rm_sorted,
     (select @r:='103') initialisation
where find_in_set(reporting_to, @r)
and length(@r := concat(@r, ',', role_id))
```

Comment: In general this cannot be solved as a query (or it needs in some data restrictions, for example, `CHECK role_id < reporting_to` constraint). Use iterative stored procedure.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6e583c388b473786d996fa17433f37d3

Comment: is there some (small) limit to the depth of recursion you need?  if not, you will need to use a stored procedure (or just upgrade to mysql 8 or mariadb)

Comment: As others have mentioned, an adjacency list model in 5.7 doesn't naturally lend itself to recursion. Consider upgrading or switching to a nested set model.

Comment: I think only iterative method is possible for this. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

mysql5.7 can never do recursive queries unless you use functions.

You can also use other languages with recursion, such as mysql5.8, oracle, java, etc., to generate a path column, like this (assuming 104 is the root node)

| id | role_id | reporting_to | path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 101 | 104/103/102/101/100 |
| 1 | 101 | 102 | 104/103/102/101 |
| 1 | 102 | 103 | 104/103/102 |
| 1 | 103 | 104 | 104/103 |